# mongoDB with nodejs return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have my own class and method call findByIdDate() When I find the data then inside of db.collection() I will get result but if I want to return that data from my own method it will come back undefined.
Could someone provide me example how to get the data please? I have been searching but I can not find any answers to this problem. I'm new to node and express
**My Method**

```
findByIdDate(){
    let data = this.db.collection('journal').find({date: this.Date}).toArray((err, result) => {
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
        console.log(result) // I have data
        return result
    })
    return data
}
```

in my other file I use it like this

```
app.post('/id', (req, res) => {

  const DIARY = new diary('new', '16 January 2020', db)
  let result = DIARY.findByIdDate()
  console.log(result) // undefined 

});
```

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve] please? Also, just wondering, could it be that the closure you give to `toArray` is executed asynchrously and that nothing is returned from `toArray()`? I'm not familiar with the JS MongoDB API, but async calls are not unheard of in the JS world.

Comment: You're probably console.logging `result` before it has been returned by `findByIdDate()`. There's a couple ways to handle this, the most modern being the use of `async/await`. This should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to do away with callback functions and make the function `async/await` as:

```
async findByIdDate(){
    try {
        let data = await this.db.collection('journal')
            .find({date: this.Date})
            .toArray() // returns a promise which can be 'awaited'
        console.log(data)
        return data
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw err
    }
}
```

And use it in your route as

```
app.post('/id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const DIARY = new diary('new', '16 January 2020', db)
        let result = await DIARY.findByIdDate()
        console.log(result) 
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
    }    
})
```

Comment: is absolutely correct. Let me add: The reasoning is that the call to MongoDB is asynchronous. And the return statement in your original code outside of the `find` call was being called synchronously. It returned data as `undefined` because at the time it was called, data was still `undefined`. The previous statement had yet to return anything.