# NodeJS MongoDB: How do I get data then returning synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

I'm a long time programmer (mostly Java) but new to NodeJS/Express.  The biggest problems I'm having are with async operations.  Some of my code is working fine, like when I can do a async database operation then just pass the results to res.render().

In this particular case, I'm in a route handler, and I need to make a call to a function I wrote in the controller to get something from the database, then do something else and then do the render in the route handler.  In other words, I need to run the function then return control with results back to the router.  Everything I have tried is not even compiling, just hangs, or I immediately get back two undefined values.  My current pattern is similar to the accepted solution in [mongoDB with nodejs return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789428/mongodb-with-nodejs-return-data) but I'm not getting my data back.

I've REALLY tried to understand this async/await stuff but it's just not working as I would expect.

The caller in the route handler looks like this:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    debug("app calling list:");
    const { listInsightErrors, listInsightResults } = await listInsightPeriods();
    debug("app results: %O %O", listInsightErrors, listInsightResults);
    res.render('index', {
        appConfig,
        listInsightErrors,
        listInsightResults
    });
});
```

The function I'm calling looks like this:

```
async function listInsightPeriods() {
        var sortKey = { clientId: 1, insightName: 1 };
        var listInsightErrors = {};
        var listInsightResults = {};
        client = await MongoClient.connect(appConfig.mongoUrl);
        const db = client.db(appConfig.mongoDatabase);
        const collection = db.collection('teamInsights');
        let garbage = await collection.find({})
            .project({ 'clientName': 1, 'insightName': 1 })
            .sort(sortKey)
            .toArray((errors, results) => {
                if (errors) {
                    debug('listInsightPeriods find error: %O', errors);
                } else {
                    debug('listInsightPeriods got results: %O', results);
                }
                listInsightErrors = errors;
                listInsightResults = results;
                debug("closed, returning %O %O", listInsightErrors, listInsightResults);
                return { listInsightErrors, listInsightResults };
                debug("Passed inside return");
            });
        debug("Outside of db call");
        return { listInsightErrors, listInsightResults };
    }
```

What happens is listInsightPeriods gets the data just fine, but the route handler doesn't get it, and I see the debugging output from the route handler before I see the debugging output from listInsightPeriods.  So I don't feel the route handler is waiting for the data to return.

Any help you can offer would be great.  I've read so many pages on this and I still can't get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toArray function also returns a Promise, so if you're using async/await you can try this approach in your listInsightPeriods function

```js
async function listInsightPeriods() {
  const response = {
    listInsightErrors: null,
    listInsightResults: null
  }
  try{
    client = await MongoClient.connect(appConfig.mongoUrl);
    const db = client.db(appConfig.mongoDatabase);
    const collection = db.collection('teamInsights');
    const results  = await collection.find({})
        .project({ 'clientName': 1, 'insightName': 1 })
        .sort({ clientId: 1, insightName: 1 })
        .toArray();
    debug("listInsightPeriods got results: %O", results);
    response.listInsightResults = results;
  }catch(e){
    debug("listInsightPeriods find error: %O", e);
    response.listInsightErrors = e;
  }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.  You're right, but the thing I was missing that was preventing me from getting it to work the way I thought it should was putting the whole thing in a try/catch block.  Then I can just return results from the find().

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'callback' concept.

callback is amazing.

this code is for you and i tested. it's work ok.

```
const express = require("express")
const mongo = require("mongodb")
const app = express()

const appConfig = {
  mongoUrl: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local",
  mongoDatabase: "local"
}

let client;
let dataBase;
mongo.connect(appConfig.mongoUrl, {}, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    this.client = null;
    this.dataBase = null;
    return;
  }
  client = client;
  dataBase = client.db(appConfig.mongoDatabase);
  debug("connected to database");
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  debug("Server is listening on port: 4000");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  debug("app calling list:");
  listInsightPeriods(function (error, result) {
    debug("app results: %O %O", error, result);
    res.json({
      error,
      result
    })
    // res.render("index", {
    //   appConfig,
    //   error,
    //   result
    // });
  });
});

function listInsightPeriods(callback) {
  var sortKey = { clientId: 1, insightName: 1 };
  dataBase.collection("teamInsights")
    .find({})
    .project({ clientName: 1, insightName: 1 })
    .sort(sortKey)
    .toArray((errors, results) => {
      if (errors) {
        debug("listInsightPeriods find error: %O", errors);
      } else {
        debug("listInsightPeriods got results: %O", results);
      }
      debug("closed, returning %O %O", errors, results);
      return callback(errors, results);
    });
}

function debug(...params) {
  console.log(params)
  // params.forEach(param => {
  //   console.log(param)
  // });
}
```